# Why does _session.Use method not work properly?

Tags: asp.net, async-await, aspnetboilerplate, sqlexception, using-statement

I have a job like this:

```
[UnitOfWork]
public override void Execute(CompleteIRHJobArgs args)
{
    var robotUserId = _userRepo.GetAll().Where(p => p.UserName == TestaLIMSWPConsts.LIMSRobot).Select(p => p.Id).First();

    using (_session.Use(args.TenantId, robotUserId))
    {
        _instanceReciptHeaderDomainService.SetIRHToCompleteState(args.IRHIds);
    }
}
```

I find `robotUserId` and set it as the current user. But after I step into method `SetIRHToCompleteState`, `_session.UserId.Value` is `null`. I think it is wrong behavior. My ABP version is 4.0.0.

```
public async Task SetIRHToCompleteState(List<int> irhIds)
{
    var irhs = await _instanceHeaderRepo.GetAll().Where(p => irhIds.Contains(p.Id)).ToListAsync();

    foreach (var t in irhs)
    {
        t.FlowState = FlowState.Completed;
        t.CompleteDate = Clock.Now;
        t.CompleteUserId = _session.UserId.Value;
    }
}
```

And sometimes,

> var irhs = await _instanceHeaderRepo.GetAll()...

throws exception:

> System.Transactions.TransactionInDoubtException: The transaction is in doubt. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But after step into method `SetIRHToCompleteState`, `_session.UserId.Value` is null.

`SetIRHToCompleteState` is `async` and continued running after the `using` scope was disposed.

Since `Execute` is not `async`, you cannot `await` but you can call `AsyncHelper.RunSync` instead.

```cs
// using Abp.Threading;

using (_session.Use(args.TenantId, robotUserId))
{
    AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => _instanceReciptHeaderDomainService.SetIRHToCompleteState(args.IRHIds));
}
```

This would also avoid the "open DataReader" error.

From [aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate#1646](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/1646):

> *it's called in a background thread which is not inside an async context. But it's not a problem since background job manager is already single threaded and does not cause to block many threads.*
>   *Hangfire implementation is also like that.*